# Device Rotation /spin Count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i want to count iphone **rotations/spin**.

if device is put on desk and if we spins iphone, how much **rotation/spin** it did.

thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Feasible ..
Apple dont want people to use their iPhones to spin just for Fun !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the sensors on the device do not provide the information required to recognize fast spins like that.